# why is my javascript not passing the values and giving no error messages

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following three bits of code. When i run the form using action="editName.php" it works fine, however when i try to fun the javascript it does not work. Can anyone see why it is not working?

below is my form

```
   <form id="dataForm" method="GET">
      <h2 id="formheader"> Update Name</h2>
        <div>
          <label>Product Name:</label>
          <input class="inputForm" id="orginalName" type="text" name="Name">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>New Name:</label>
          <input class="inputForm" id="newName" type="text" name="newName">
        </div>
        <div id="theSubmit">
          <button id="editButton">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

below is my sql

```
if ($Name !="" && $newName !=""){ 
     $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_NAME = '$newName' WHERE P_Name = '$Name'";
     $conn->exec($sql);
```

below is my javascript

```
function updateProduct(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var productName = document.getElementById("originalName").value;
  var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value;
  if(productName != "" && newName != ""){
    var url = "editName.php?Name=" + productName + "&newName=" + newName;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
submitButton = document.getElementById("editButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", updateProduct);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in js?

Comment: no error displays in my console @Kushal

Comment: You should add `return false` to `updateProduct` to prevent the default form submission.

Comment: How are you setting `$Name` and `$newName`?

Comment: You said you are using  `action="editForm.php"` and in your js url is ' "editName.php'. Is it intentionl or typo?

Comment: Please use !empty($Name) and isset($Name) ...

Comment: Is your request being initiated and is successful?

Comment: What is productID. Where is come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input id = orginalName, but you looking for or**i**ginalName

And please, read [about SQL-injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

Use $.post because this is a one line code so it is so easy
like

```
$.post('url',{var1:'value1',var2:'value2'},function(data){
alert(data);
});
```